# finding whether the divergence test is applicable on given sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Find whether the divergence test is applicable for sequence
>   $$a_{n}=e^{-\frac{6}{n}}$$If applicable, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=$

What I've tried:

I did not understand how the divergence test is applied here.

But I am getting: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-\frac{6}{n}}=e^{-\infty}=0$$

Can anyone please explain me how can I apply the divergence test here? Thanks.

Comment: As $n$ approaches infinity, $6/n$ approaches $0$, so $a_n$ approaches _______?

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=1.$

Comment: Right, so now what does that say about convergence?

Comment: Thanks quasi. But i did not understand is Divergence test is applicable here or not.

Comment: Is it a series, or just a sequence? The divergence test applies to series.

Comment: It is just a sequence.

Comment: A sequence converges if the terms approach a finite limit.

Comment: So we can say that in sequence  we can not apply Divergence Test. Is i am right.

Comment: The divergence test doesn't apply to sequences.

Comment: Ok. Thanks sp much quasi. I have got it.

Comment: No problem. I think at this point, you might as well delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is wrong.
$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{-6}{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{6}{n}} = 0
$.
And it's a sequence, you can't apply divergent test here.